# delete a directory that has one file but don't have another

Tags: bash, find

In bash, how to delete all directories that have a file named "1b912" but don't have another file named "completed.touch"?

To delete all directories that don't have "completed.touch", i use:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/completed.touch" ';' -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

But I am not sure how to add the second condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I am not sure how to add the second condition

Just add another `-exec` for testing if directory has an entry named `1b912`.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
   '!' -exec test -e '{}/completed.touch' ';' \
       -exec test -e '{}/1b912' ';' \
       -exec rm -r '{}' +
```